# Vb.Net How to create Months/Years dropdown lists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Which is the best way to create two dropdown lists one with months (maybe month names) and the other one with years?

They should return two values with this format: 1 (or 2, 3 etc.) for months and 2014 (or 2013, 2012 etc.) for years

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looping will be the best for your solution.
Create a for loop for year as follow

```
 for(int i=2000;i<2020;i++)
 {
      ddYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
 }
```

and for month

```
 DateTime month = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2000");
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
 {
      DateTime NextMont = month.AddMonths(i);
      ListItem list = new ListItem();
      list.Text = NextMont.ToString("MMMM");
      list.Value = NextMont.Month.ToString();
      MyddlMonthList.Items.Add(list);
 }
```

In VB

```
Dim month As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2000")
  For i As Integer = 0 To 11
    Dim NextMont As DateTime = month.AddMonths(i)
    Dim list As New ListItem()
    list.Text = NextMont.ToString("MMMM")
    list.Value = NextMont.Month.ToString()
    MyddlMonthList.Items.Add(list)
  Next
```

Comment: you need to change it in vb.

Answer (score 1):

Other way we can able to do like this,

**VB Listbox,**

```
Dim months = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.MonthNames
For Each month As String In months
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(month) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(month)
    End If
Next
```

Or Else

```
ListBox1.DataSource = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.MonthNames
```

**VB Combobox,**

```
Dim months = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.MonthNames
For Each month As String In months
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(month) Then
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(month)
    End If
Next
```

Or Else

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.MonthNames
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

DropDownList ddltmp = new DropDownList();
int curYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

for(int i = 1; i < 76; ++i)
{

ListItem tmp = new ListItem();
tmp.Value = curYear.ToString();

tmp.Text = curYear.ToString();

ddltmp.Items.Add(tmp);

curYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(i).Year;
}

this.form1.Controls.Add(ddltmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have the current year with the previous years,this is the simplest answer :)

```
 int curYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        for (int i = curYear; i >= 2006; i--)
        {
            ddYear.Items.Add(i.ToString());

        }
```